# UINavigationBar set image not completely drawn

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to set image to ViewController for the navigationBar,
after setting its not completely drawn to the NavigationBar.
Unable to understand why its happening.

The Image size is 90 height and width 750

Can any on let me know what i need to do?

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Dashboar", @"Dashboard");
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
UIImage *currentImage =  [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]
                          resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:currentImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

[image]

Comment: Does it change anything if you change the translucent property of nav bar ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks, Its enabled i make it disable its work.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Dashboar", @"Dashboard");
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

you have to set  the exact width of this backgrounds images for multiple devices.

```
if (IS_IPHONE4) {
[navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar_iphone4.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
if (IS_IPHONE5) {
[navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar_iphone5.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
if (IS_IPHONE6) {
[navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar_iphone6.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
if (IS_IPHONE6Plus) {
[navController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar_iphone6plus.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 }
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationPortraitBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have to checked this code work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a translucent issue,From iOS 7+ By default, the translucent property is `YES`. Disable it by

```
   self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```